# Remove punctuation mark from the list using translate and maketrans function

Tags: python, punctuation

Need to remove the punctuation marks from the list and then save it in the same list

**Code :**

```
sentences = ["Hi! How are you doing?","Hope everything is fine.","Have an amazing day!"]
type(list1)
sentences = sentences.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

**Error :**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7b3b0cbf9c58> in <module>()
      1 sentences = ["Hi! How are you doing?","Hope everything is fine.","Have an amazing day!"]
      2 type(list1)
----> 3 sentences = sentences.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the truth. A list does not have a `translate` attribute — a string does. You need to call this on the strings in the list, not the list itself. A list comprehension is good for that. Here you can call `translate()` on each string in the list:

```
import string

sentences = ["Hi! How are you doing?","Hope everything is fine.","Have an amazing day!"]

trans = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

[s.translate(trans) for s in sentences]
# ['Hi How are you doing', 'Hope everything is fine', 'Have an amazing day']
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! This helped a lot.